# How can i make time based loop in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I so far have a game that runs at 60 fps,but i need the character to have a animation for when he is walking. I have looked at sources for days but have come up empty on how to make this time based loop work. If you could create a example and explain how it works i would be so thankful!

Comment: I suggest you show some sample code.

Comment: Have the character keep track of what frame (of the game) it started its animation on, then display the next frame of the animation when enough game frames have gone by.

Answer (score 0):

Change animation every 1 second (1000ms) - using pygame ticks.

```
current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

next_move = current_time + 1000 # 1s = 1000ms

# mainloop
while True:

   current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

   if next_move <= current_time:
      change_animation()
      next_move = current_time + 1000
```

This code not depends on FPS.